# How to not overwrite the lines of a file when in a loop?

Tags: c, file-io, fwrite

I have a text file which has blocks of data. The blocks are a struct. Each block has a number of records, in my example each block has 12 records. What I want to do is to sort each block and write it in another file that I've called `sortedFile` This is my code, I didn't post the whole code because it would be too much.

```
while(counter < numOfBlocks){
    fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(block_t), fileOp);

    //get the blocks
    //buffer->blockid = firstBlock;

    for(uint i = 0; i < buffer->nreserved; i++){
        for(uint j = i; j < buffer->nreserved; j++){
            if(buffer->entries[i].num > buffer->entries[j].num){
                smallest = buffer->entries[j].num;
                buffer->entries[j].num = buffer->entries[i].num;
                buffer->entries[i].num = smallest;

                //keep the record id's
                uint smallestID = buffer->entries[j].recid;
                buffer->entries[j].recid = buffer->entries[i].recid;
                buffer->entries[i].recid = smallestID;

                fwrite(&buffer, 1, sizeof(block_t), sortedFile);
                //fscanf(sortedFile,"Record id: %d, Num: %d", buffer->entries[i].recid, smallest);
            }

        }


    }
    counter++;
}
```

This while loop is doing exactly what I want. The blocks get sorted by their `buffer->entries[].num` field and it is written in the `sortedFile` then I update the counter and I start the for loop again and I have the impression that the for loop is writing the data over the data from the previous loop. Here is how I print out the contents of `sortedFile`. As a result I get only the sorted values of the last block.

```
  //print out contents of sortedFile
int z = 0;

printf("This is the sorted file: \n");
while(z < reserved){
    fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(block_t), sortedFile);
    printf("Block id: %d, Record id: %d, Num: %d\n", buffer->blockid, buffer->entries[z].recid,
                                                         buffer->entries[z].num);
    z++;
}

fclose(sortedFile);
```

How can I show my program to show to the next segment of the file to write the new data? I'm thinking of using fwrite with some sort of pointer of the size of the block, that gets updated everytime the loop is being run, but I'm not that experienced and I can't get it right.

Comment: When do you open and close the `sortedFile`? When you are opening the file for writing, there is a flag to specify whether you want to replace the file or append to it. See http://http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: I open the sorted file with this line `sortedFile = fopen("sortedFile.bin", "a");` just before the while loop. I changed the flag from `w` to `a` as you said and I still get the same result.

Comment: amongst other problems, a block is being written to the output file EVERY time through the inner loop of the nested loop sort function.   Strongly suggest only writing a block to the output file after the sorting of that block is complete.

Comment: in the output code, eliminate the 'z' and the 'reserved'.   use the fread() as the loop control.  I.E. 'while( fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(block_t), sortedFile) )'

Comment: this line: 'printf("Block id: %d, Record id: %d, Num: %d\n", buffer->blockid, buffer->entries[z].recid, buffer->entries[z].num);' only prints one entry from each block read.   The first block gets the first entry printed.  The second block gets the second entry printed,  etc.   Strongly suggest:  1) in a 'while' loop, read a block,  print the common info from the block, in a 'for' loop, print the info from each entry in that block.

Comment: I can't make it work with the fread() in the while loop.It doesn't print anything. How am I going to get the entries if I don't use the z that I have?